# May I ask this question on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

Before posting this question, I wanted to get feedback on where the best place to ask it would be, if any. The question’s aim is to verify that my current plan is on the right track given my intentions.

> #### Exporting backend Python scripts to the web, while staying connected to a GUI
>
> Before starting on what could be a time-consuming project, I need to
>   verify that the following plan is sound.
>
> I have a desktop app (made with wxPython, if it matters) which is
>   directly connected to Python scripts that extract data from the web.
>   These files need to run 24/7, so they need to be separated from the
>   GUI, to run even when it’s closed. However, the data still needs to
>   feed the GUI when it is open, continuously refreshing it. This
>   presently occurs with threading in the desktop GUI.
>
> The plan is to use Flask and PyMySQL on PythonAnywhere to keep the
>   backend scripts running. I assume there should be no problem
>   connecting the resulting data feed to either a web-interface or the
>   aforementioned desktop interface. I also assume that continual
>   refreshing via getting data through PyMySQL should perform similarly
>   in seamlessness to the original desktop version.
>
> Is there is something flawed with this plan, or is there a clear way
>   that it can be improved?

Comment: It's likely the question would be closed as *too broad*.

Comment: You don't have a specific programming problem, both because your problem isn't specific, and because you don't actually have a problem.

Comment: I see. Do you think there a sub category on StackExchange where I could post it?

Comment: I don't think there's a site in the network that takes such a question.

Comment: Is this question invalid for this Meta category (I assume so due to the downvotes)?

Comment: @Phillip Well it's pretty poorly researched; you should really be looking through the how to ask guidelines in the help center before asking a question like this.  The question you're asking about isn't really borderline...

Comment: @Servy Okay, well it saved time, so I guess this process is valid on some level

Comment: @Phillip You wasted a lot of both your time, and the time of others, by not bothering to try to figure out if the question was appropriate yourself.  You should be more considerate in the future, rather than continuing to post low quality questions and not caring about the consequences so long as you get what you want.

Comment: @Servy That is a bit presumptuous don't you think? I actually spent time today researching a Flask (and a few other options) overview, and this question seeks to verify where I'm currently leaning

Comment: @Servy That was my last comment, now time is being wasted. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Phillip I was speaking about your meta question.  I don't know enough about the subject matter of that other question to comment on how well researched it is.

Comment: @Servy Ok, an additional comment. I could have phrased that reply better. The fact that I put time into various potential paths regarding the subject matter at hand should suggest that there is a place to post this (i.e. Perhaps not even on any StackExchange category -- That is a lot to sift through, right? -- where someone else could answer quickly). Based on prior experience in SO, it still wasn't clear where that may be. Where to ask, if not Meta? Thanks for your time and anyone else. I apologize if I'm mistaken and time was wasted.

Comment: I downvoted because the question you're asking about would not be on-topic for Stack Overflow, and I don't see any way you could possible make it on-topic. I don't speak for the scopes of any other site on the Stack Exchange network, so if you want to pursue that avenue of inquiry, you should consult the [list of sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic), read about their topicality, find one that seems the closest, then ask this same question on their meta.

Comment: @gnat while that is relevant to the discussion here, this is definitely not a duplicate of that. Contrary to popular belief people are allowed to ask about specific questions and get specific advice here.

Comment: Perhaps the question would have been better for Meta StackExchange and the question rephrased to something like 'Is this question valid for any StackExchange forum'. I understand if some might even consider that vague, but would be worth it to me to potentially save time, and I don't believe should waste anyone's time unless they are meandering to begin with in my opinion (i.e. instead of briefly reviewing and continuing if not having some direction or input).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An initial reading of your question suggests that you're still "stuck at the whiteboard" with your implementation.  For that reason, your question isn't suitable for Stack Overflow, as there's a lot of subjectivity and opinion that could be taken from what you're stating.

We do well with questions which can be concisely answered and are as unambiguous as possible.  "Is this the right approach"-type questions will encourage ambiguous answers and have no defined correctness associated with them.

Comment: Accepted as it answers the title question, but perhaps it should have been posted in Meta StackExchange as something like 'Is this question valid for any StackExchange forum'

Comment: @Phillip The StackExchange sites are not forums, as explained by this question's answers: [Are Stack Exchange sites forums?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/are-stack-exchange-sites-forums)

Comment: @Davy M  While it's a type of forum according to the definition [1], I would agree that the word forum could be misleading in salient/prominent instances.

[1] a medium where ideas and views on a particular issue can be exchanged

Comment: @Phillip but Stack Exchange isn't meant to discuss ideas and views. It is meant to ask and solve specific and practical programming issues. Tryong to discuss views and high level ideas is likely to get your post closed (either too broad, or primarily opinion based)

Comment: @Patrice, this was already understood (in the colloquial sense of the word). Posting and discussing answers, for instance, is subsumed by the broader notion of exchanging ideas. It is a type of forum in that sense, and that's what I meant by it.